# Datagrid events not working inside a titlepane

Tags: events, datagrid, dojo

I am new to Dojo and trying to create Datagrid that can be expanded on click. So, I have decided to put the datagrid inside a titlepane, so that the datagrid can be shown on expanding titlepane.

titlepane works great, i can set the data grid inside. Everything fine so far. The only problem is, I couldn't get the click events inside the datagrid. ( i couldnt do row selection, sort, etc.)

I am using dojo 1.8.3 and here is my code

function(taskListModel){
    var tasks = taskListModel.getData();

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/TitlePane", "dojo/dom"], function(ready, TitlePane, dom){
    ready(function(){
        taskListTitlePane = new dijit.TitlePane({title:"Click here to see Task List", content: "Collapse me!"});
        dom.byId("taskListTitlePane").appendChild(taskListTitlePane.domNode);
        createTaskDataGrid(tasks);      
    });
});}
```

grid creation:

```
var createTaskDataGrid = function(tasks){
```

/*set up data store*/
    var data = {
      identifier: "id",
      items: []
    };

```
// push the data into items
for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++){
data.items.push(lang.mixin({ id: i+1 }, tasks[i]));
}
var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

/*set up layout*/
var layout = [[
  {'name': 'S.No', 'field': 'id', 'width': '10%'},
  {'name': 'TaskName', 'field': 'task_name', 'width': '20%'},
  {'name': 'Assignee', 'field': 'assignee', 'width': '20%'},
  {'name': 'Module', 'field': 'module_name', 'width': '20%'},
  {'name': 'DueDate', 'field': 'taskid', 'width': '15%'},
  {'name': 'Status', 'field': 'status', 'width': '15%'}
]];

/*create a new grid*/
var grid = new DataGrid({
id: 'grid',
store: store,
structure: layout,
rowSelector: '20px',
autoHeight: true});

/*append the new grid to the div*/
grid.placeAt("tasklistscroller");

/*Call startup() to render the grid*/
grid.startup();

grid.on("RowClick", function(evt){
    var idx = evt.rowIndex,
    rowData = grid.getItem(idx);
    //console.log("row data is = " + rowData.task_name + " " + rowData.taskid);
    mainController.taskSelected(rowData.taskid, rowData.task_name);
}, true);


if(taskListTitlePane !== null){
    console.log("setting grid inside title pane");
    taskListTitlePane.setContent(grid.domNode);
    //taskListTitlePane.containerNode.appendChild(grid.domNode); 
}}
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code for connecting the onClick event with the data grid after the grid startup.

```
 dojo.connect(grid,'onRowClick',function(event) {
        var idx = event.rowIndex,
        rowData = grid.getItem(idx);
        //console.log("row data is = " + rowData.task_name + " " + rowData.taskid);
        mainController.taskSelected(rowData.taskid, rowData.task_name);
    });
```

Also for sorting please use `grid.canSort = true;`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I have tried this solution. But still I am not getting the click events.

Comment: hey..can u put an alert inside the function and check if its entering the method...Also are u getting any javascript error ?

Comment: Hi, I tried.. but no help.. The function is not called at all.

Comment: An update with this question: click event is working if i try to click in the left most corner of a row inside the data grid. Still trying to figure out the reason